# Issue With Resetting Password using a update md5 password

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to use a html form to reset passwords to a hashed md5 password. I will include all of my code. i get a blank screen when i submit the form. I am a beginner so please keep that in mind. I check myphpadmin and the hashed password does not change.

```
<html>
<head><title> Administrator reset password page</title></head>
<body>
<form action="forgotpass.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>User Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="password" /></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" name="user" /></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Reset Password"/></td>      </tr> 
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
include "connect.php"
$tmpPass = $_POST['password'];
$tmpuser= $_POST['user'];


$tmpPass = md5($tmpPass);


$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE employee set pass = $tmpPass WHERE usr = $tmpuser");

// Performs the $sql query on the server to insert the values
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo 'Password Has Been Reset Successfully';



/*
$email_message.= "Hello  ";
$email_message.= "User with username: " .$tmpUser. "\n";
$email_message.= "Your New password:  " .$_POST['password']. "\n";
$email_to = "registration@joshuamoorehead.com";
$email_subject = "Registration";
*/

else {
 echo 'Error: '. $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why are you performing the same query twice?

Comment: You definitely don't want to use md5 to hash passwords. See http://php.net/password_hash for how you should be doing it.

Comment: Your form variables Name=`"password"` and Password=`"user"` are the wrong way around too. Please at least go through your code to omit basic mistakes.

Comment: Thank you and noted. After staring at the same thing for a lengthy period of time only someone elses eyes help

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around your string values:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE employee set pass = '$tmpPass' WHERE usr = '$tmpuser'");
```

Also, why are you running your query a second time?

```
// Performs the $sql query on the server to insert the values
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { // <-- HERE
  echo 'Password Has Been Reset Successfully';
```

Your `$sql` variable will contain the boolean result of your query, you need to check that variable is true as opposed to running the query again:

```
if($sql === true) {
  echo 'Password Has Been Reset Successfully';
```

Comment: I thought that <$conn->query($sql) == true checks to see if the process completes succesfully and gives the echo.

Comment: You would use `mysql_effected_rows()` for that